# How to disable a html element trough css or javascript that already have the "visibility: visible !important;" attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<span class="powered-by" style=" display: block !important; visibility: visible !important;">
...
</span>
```

I'm using a certain add-on on something you could kinda call a website builder.

It has this really annoying element which brings down the credibility of my site, but I don't have access to the actual HTML of this add-on. I do have access to some general CSS files.

I tried to be smart by adding the following lines to the CSS file:

```
.powered-by {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

I also tried it with !important behind it, but that didn't change anything.

This is what I get in the Styles window when I use the developer tools from chrome (Inspect Element):

```
element.style {
    display: block !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}
rating-demo-style3.css
.powered-by {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #4a4f56;
    opacity: .4;
}
theme.scss.css?11648440341067719346
.powered-by {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The file I have access to is theme.scss.css, but obviously, it just strikes that one through because it is lower.

How do I go about making this element invisible or just deleting it from the page?

(If it's not possible with css, I also have access to a general javascript file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since what you want is to hide an element, have you tried with making it absolute and moving it out of the way?

```
.powered-by {
  position: absolute;
  left: -99999px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It's not on the screen anymore which was the initial purpose!

Answer (score 1):

You have an inline style which also has the `!important` declaration -- that's the highest **[level of specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**. You **cannot** override this with CSS. However, you **can** override this with JavaScript, by simply replacing the value.

To do this, you'll want to grab the element (probably with **[`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)**), and then modify the **[`style.display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)** property, as can be seen in the following:

```js
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('powered-by')[0];
element.style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<span class="powered-by" style=" display: block !important; visibility: visible !important;">Element</span>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your solution would work, but I can't really find the place to put it in the 10k javascript file (the add-on loads fairly late)
But changing the positions worked and was easier

Comment: Or, with JS / jQuery, you could "wrap" the element with a div or similar, and put `display: none` on _that_ element.... - or, if we're using javascript, we could just _remove_ the element.... javascript opens a world of possibilities....